# Retrieving env var with leading slash from python in git bash shell on Windows 10

Tags: python, bash, git, windows-10, environment-variables

I need to define an env var with a leading slash to be retrieved from within a python Django app running in a git bash shell on Windows 10.

The env var gets retrieved incorrectly from within the python session as shown below.

```
$ echo $STATIC_URL

$ export STATIC_URL=/static/
$ echo $STATIC_URL
/static/
$ python
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 
bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('STATIC_URL')
'C:/Program Files/Git/static/'
>>>
```

How can I set the STATIC_URL env var so that it will be retrieved correctly from within the python session? I need python to retrieve it as '/static/' just like bash does, not 'C:/Program Files/Git/static/'.

Comment: Try [dotenv](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv/)

Comment: I don't think Python does any processing of the envvars, so I'd assume the CWD expansion is performed by windows somehow. Have you tried quoting the value, or launching a cmd session and checking out what the envvar is from there?

Comment: Quoting doesn't help, and actually the value retrieved is not the CWD, but rather under the directory in which git is installed.

Comment: The problem does not reproduce in a regular Windows cmd session. Only in a git bash shell. But I need to be able to run in a bash shell.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari dotenv does the trick! Thanks very much for the tip! Please enter your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Your reproduction steps work for me on WSL. So you have clearly left out some important detail(s). For example, what is a  "git bash shell"?

Comment: @KurtisRader A git bash shell is what you get by downloading git on Windows 10 (from https://git-scm.com/download/win). I am running git bash directly on Windows 10. I don't have WSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv/) 
 for setting environment variables for your sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue using Git Bash on Windows and I just needed a quick solution and portability wasn't a concern. Adding an extra `/` worked for me.

To check the environment variable, I used this Python code called `src/test.py`:

```py
import os

print(os.environ.get('STATIC_URL', ""))
```

then in Bash without an extra forward slash

```sh
$ export STATIC_URL="/app" && python src/test.py
C:/Program Files/Git/app
```

Now with the extra forward slash:

```sh
$ export STATIC_URL="//app" && python src/test.py
/app
```